# How to Monitor memory leak in android thereby finding all the objects causing the leak

Tags: java, android, object, memory, memory-leaks

I want to monitor the memory usage of the android application and want to get all the objects of particular class or activity causing the memory leak. Googled a lot to find a solution, got some references which did not work out. This is one of the references https://acadgild.com/blog/android-devices-memory-management/ which i found bit useful but did not get the end result.

And found one android plugin called [JVM Debugger Memory View](http://JVM%20Debugger%20Memory%20View)

from this also i did not get the expected result.

So can anyone help me out in finding the memory leak and thereby collecting the objects which are causing the memory leak in my android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has released a library called https://github.com/square/leakcanary

in google io 2016.
which helps in getting the objects which are causing the memory leak in the android app.